# How to set Url of ajax call via data_url property of submit button with the use of Url.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have learned that in order to set URL for an ajax call, I can always set the URL.Action in the control which triggers the ajax call like below:

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.Companies,
"Please Select", new { @class = "form-control",
data_url = Url.Action("ListOfCoverLetterByCompanyId", "Referral") })
```

JS

```
  $('#CompanyId').change(function () {
        var companyId = $(this).val();
        var url = $(this).data('url');
       // make the ajax call
```

Now I want to follow same approach when I need to make an ajax call on form submit. Something like below:

View

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create"
    data_url="@Url.Action("CheckForExistingReferral","Referral")" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        var canSubmit = false;
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            if (!canSubmit) {
                e.preventDefault();
                debugger;
                var data = $('form').serialize();
             // getting error in below line
                var url = e.data('url'); // e represents the source element. 
                // how to get URL from submit button
               // var url = '/Referral/CheckForExistingReferral';
               // MAke Ajax call

    </script>
}
```

Comment: use `data-url="..."` instead of `data_url="..."`

Comment: Your handling the forms `.submit()` event, so that data attribute should be in the `<form>` element, not the button (alternatively you could find the button in the form but that would be unnecessary)

Comment: `data_url` used in HTML helper, for HTML tag use `data-url` instead.

Comment: But why not use use `@Html.BeginForm()` to generate the correct `action` attribute, then you can access the value from that attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke: You mean to say I can do the same thing but set the Url.Action at the form level. then I can use $(this) keyword and get the Url too? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes - `@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckForExistingReferral", "Referral")` will generate `action="/Referral/CheckForExistingReferral` so you can use `$(this).attr('action')`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sir, what if my ajax post destination is different from my actual `httppost` form post.

Comment: I mean ajax call might be hitting some another controller action, but actual form submit has to hit some another controller action

Comment: Then you can always use `new { data_url = '@Url.Action(...)` }` in the `BeginForm()` method to generate it and use `$(this).data('url')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153583/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

just give it an id or class:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create"
    data-url="@Url.Action("CheckForExistingReferral","Referral")" class="btn btn-default" id="submit-btn" />
```

and then use it easily for selecting:

```
var url = $('#submit-btn').data('url');
```

And also as Alex Kudryashev mentioned, you have to change the `data_url` to `data-url`.

Comment: But I wanted to use the source event trigger handle "e". Can I make use of that?

Comment: `$('form').submit(function (e) {`